# firefox prevent ctrl + shift + p shortcut from opening a private browser window

Tags: javascript, firefox, events, preventdefault, onkeydown

my code:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 80){
        e.preventDefault()
        alert('test')
    }
}
```

The shortcut does not work, and opens a firefox private browser window, is there a way around this?

Comment: No, there isn't. You cannot stop browser level key combinations on your page.

Comment: Perhaps you should focus on [the problem you're trying to solve, not this particular solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346503/what-is-the-opposite-of-the-xy-problem)

Comment: It is not possible. Shortcut priorties: `OS > Application > Websites`